# First Derivative Test Clarification Needed

Tags: calculus

To my understanding relative extrema will occur at critical points if the derivative goes from positive to negative (local max) or vice versa (local min).

Critical points are defined as wherever the derivative=0 or where the derivative does not exist.

However, it seems that there are exceptions to this rule when the derivative does not exist, eg 1/x^2.

So should the first derivative test only include critical points where f'(x)= 0?

Comment: What kind of exceptions do you have in mind?

Comment: The first derivative test works only when $f$ is continuous at the point where the sign of the derivative changes. See  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Precise_statement_of_first_derivative_test). $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Of course. If the function is not continuous at a point then it is not differentiable at that point. So it would make no sense to speak about the first derivative test at points of discontinuity.

Comment: I see, so even in the case of a function like y = |x| where the first derivative test would work and f'(x) does not exist, the first derivative test should still not be applied? I guess the absolute value function is continuous so the first derivative test can still be applied.

Comment: So which response is correct: Can the first derivative test be used for all continuous functions. Or the first derivative test can only be used where the derivative exists?

Comment: To be more precise on my comment: The first derivative test applies at points where the function is continuous but not differentable, like $x_0=0$ for $y=|x|$. But it does not apply if the function is disconitnuous at some point

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Also: it is not correct to say that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is discontinuous at $x_0=0$. It is actually not defined at $x_0=0$ so it is not meaningful to characterize it as continuous or discontinuous. These terms only make sense for points of the domain of the function. So, $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous in its domain.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding relative extrema will occur at critical points if the derivative goes from positive to negative (local max) or vice versa (local min). Critical points are defined as wherever the derivative=0 or where the derivative does not exist.

That's more or less correct. To be precise, the rule is that given a function $f$, if $f$ has a relative extremum at $x$, then $x$ is a critical point of $f$.

> However, it seems that there are exceptions to this rule when the derivative does not exist, eg 1/x^2.

That's not an exception to the rule. That function doesn't have any relative extrema, so it can't provide any exceptions to the rule.

Maybe you're thinking that the rule says, "If a function $f$ has a critical point $x$, then $f$ has a relative extremum at $x$." But that's not what the rule says.

Comment: I see I've gotten a downvote. Does my answer need to be improved? Did I misunderstand the question?